# How to use flux with firebase's sometimes synchronous callbacks

Tags: firebase, flux

I am trying to use flux with firebase, and found out that the Firebase.on() callbacks are sometimes triggered synchronously by a Firebase.set() called within the same client.

This does not jive with the flux pattern of dispatching an action when the user triggers a firebase set and another one when the value comes back, which will break the multiple dispatch invariant.

A workaround would be to delay the mutation calls with process.nextTick(). Is there a way to force the callbacks to be called in the next tick instead, like how promises work? Or is there a recommended pattern here?

Comment: The recommended pattern is to not differentiate between local and remote events. Both should be extremely fast. Both should be handled by the same event handlers without any if/else logic. Don't think in remote or local, think in terms of synchronized data shared across the cloud. There is no built-in tool to Firebase to force nextTick().